# Sending "User-agent" using Requests library in Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I want to send a value for `"User-agent"` while requesting a webpage using Python Requests.  I am not sure is if it is okay to send this as a part of the header, as in the code below:

```
debug = {'verbose': sys.stderr}
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response  = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent, config=debug)
```

The debug information isn't showing the headers being sent during the request.

Is it acceptable to send this information in the header?  If not, how can I send it?

Answer (score 486, accepted):

The `user-agent` should be specified as a field in the header.

Here is a [list of HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), and you'd probably be interested in [request-specific fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields), which includes `User-Agent`.

#### If you're using requests v2.13 and newer

The simplest way to do what you want is to create a dictionary and specify your headers directly, like so:

```
import requests

url = 'SOME URL'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
    'From': 'youremail@domain.example'  # This is another valid field
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

#### If you're using requests v2.12.x and older

Older versions of `requests` clobbered default headers, so you'd want to do the following to preserve default headers and then add your own to them.

```
import requests

url = 'SOME URL'

# Get a copy of the default headers that requests would use
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

# Update the headers with your custom ones
# You don't have to worry about case-sensitivity with
# the dictionary keys, because default_headers uses a custom
# CaseInsensitiveDict implementation within requests' source code.
headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
    }
)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You can also access the headers you sent with `response.request.headers` , this works because the original request object is an attribute of the response object. See also [http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#request-and-response-objects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#request-and-response-objects)

Comment: The default value is also available as requests.utils.default_user_agent() if you want to just augment that with your own info.

Comment: It's not correct. It clobbers the rest of the headers. He should get a copy of defaults from requests.utils.default_user_agent() and update it, and send those.

Comment: for easyness, on https://httpbin.org/headers (downloadable stuff) you can get the browser headers then make your query appear you

Comment: At least in `2.13.0`, the headers are not clobbered and the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) just tell you to use the `headers` kwarg.

Answer (score 99):

It's more convenient to use a [session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#id1), this way you don't have to remember to set headers each time:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Custom user agent'})

session.get('https://httpbin.org/headers')
```

By default, session also manages cookies for you. In case you want to disable that, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037668/how-to-disable-cookie-handling-with-the-python-requests-library).

Answer (score 14):

It will send the request like browser

```
import requests

url = 'https://Your-url'
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

response= requests.get(url.strip(), headers=headers, timeout=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative for `session.headers.update()`

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Custom user agent'

session.get('https://httpbin.org/headers')
```