# Requests session without cookies or other tracking?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to use a requests session object to set an HTTPAdaptor on the connection. I don't however want to actually track a session. That is, I don't wish to have cookies, or any other persistent data, stored and potentially sent with further requests.

Is there an easy way to disable this session tracking, or perhaps is there a way to use an HTTPAdapter without a session?

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037668/how-to-disable-cookie-handling-with-the-python-requests-library)

the tl;dr is

```
from http import cookiejar  # Python 2: import cookielib as cookiejar
class BlockAll(cookiejar.CookiePolicy):
    return_ok = set_ok = domain_return_ok = path_return_ok = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: False
    netscape = True
    rfc2965 = hide_cookie2 = False

s = requests.Session()
s.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll())

s.get("https://httpbin.org/cookies/set?foo=bar")
assert not s.cookies
```

Comment: Why not just vote to close this question as a dupe then?