# Python Requests Login to 9gag

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, cookies, web-scraping

I am trying to login to 9gag with python using requests lib. I inspected the post packets with firebug, found out that a csrftoken was used. Eventually I have managed to get the csrftoken and make the request with it.

But when I post the login parameters, I get a page with an error that says "**disable** cookies to login". I use a requests session to keep the login cookies.

My problem is that I can't get the links to nsfw posts if I don't login. 
Should I maybe tinker around with the HTTP Headers?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import os
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

class Ninegaginstance():
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.s = requests.Session()
        self.s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3'
        csrf = self.get_csrf(self.s.get('http://m.9gag.com/login').text)
        payload = OrderedDict([('csrftoken', csrf), ('password', password),
        ('username', username)])
        print(payload)
        self.login(payload)
        self.getpage()

    def get_csrf(self, source):
        match_csrf = re.compile('(name=\"csrftoken\" value=\")([\w\d]+)')
        return match_csrf.search(source).group(2)

    def login(self, credentials):
        loginpage = self.s.post('http://m.9gag.com/login', params=credentials)
        print(loginpage.status_code)
        print(self.s.cookies)
        with open('login.html', 'w') as loginpagefile:
            print(loginpage.text, file=loginpagefile)

    def getpage(self):
        ninegagpage = self.s.get('http://m.9gag.com')
        with open('9gagsource.html', 'w') as ninegagfile:
            print(ninegagpage.text, file=ninegagfile)

newninegaginstance = Ninegaginstance('myusername', 'mypassword')
```

Comment: Have you tried blocking all cookies like this answer suggests ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21714597/170005

Comment: @fixxxer I've tried now. Still getting the same error, **disable** cookie to login. But s.cookies is empty.