# Cookie policy getting ignored?

Tags: python, python-requests, cookielib, cookiejar

I'm trying to use [requests.Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) to make some requests and I'd like cookies to not be set. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037668/how-to-disable-cookie-handling-with-the-python-requests-library), it appears I can create a cookie policy, and create a cookie jar given that policy to ignore cookies. However, for my requests, it would seem that cookies are still be set:

```
from http import cookiejar

class BlockAll(cookiejar.CookiePolicy):
        """ Blocks all cookies for a given request.
        """
        return_ok = set_ok = domain_return_ok = path_return_ok = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: False
        netscape = True
        rfc2965 = hide_cookie2 = False


def get_cookie_jar():
    cookies = cookiejar.CookieJar(policy=BlockAll())
    return cookies

session = requests.Session()
response = session.request(
   method='post',
   url='some_url.com',
   cookies=get_cookie_jar(),
   ....
)

print(response.cookies)
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='JSESSIONID', value='1234', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='some_url.com', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

Is this the correct way to set the policy for this type of request? Any help / links to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cookies` argument to `request(...)` lets you specify outgoing cookies **on the request**. It is not consulted for incoming cookies **on the response**.

You need to set the policy on the session:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll())
```

Demo:

```
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> response = session.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?foo=bar')
>>> session.cookies  # no policy, so cookie got set
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='foo', value='bar', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='httpbin.org', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
>>> session.cookies.clear()  # clean slate, no cookies
>>> session.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
>>> session.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll())
>>> response = session.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?foo=bar')
>>> session.cookies  # with policy, cookies still empty
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```