# python requests bot detection?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been using the `requests` library to mine this website. I haven't made too many requests to it within 10 minutes. Say 25. All of a sudden, the website gives me a 404 error.

My question is: I read somewhere that getting a URL with a browser is different from getting a URL with something like a `requests`. Because the `requests` fetch does not get cookies and other things that a browser would. Is there an option in `requests` to emulate a browser so the server doesn't think i'm a bot? Or is this not an issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, at least one thing you can do is to send `User-Agent` header:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Besides `requests`, you can simulate a real user by using [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) - it uses a real browser - in this case there is clearly no easy way to distinguish your automated user from other  users. Selenium can also make use a "headless" browser.

Also, check if the web-site you are scraping provides an API. If there is no API or you are not using it, make sure you know if the site actually allows automated web-crawling like this, study `Terms of use`. You know, there is probably a reason why they block you after too many requests per a period of time.

Also see:

- [Sending "User-agent" using Requests library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/how-to-send-user-agent-in-requests-library-in-python)
- [Headless Selenium Testing with Python and PhantomJS](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.U0VkX61dXLY)

edit1: selenium uses a webdriver rather than a real browser; i.e., it passes a `webdriver = TRUE` in the header, making it far easier to detect than `requests`.

Answer (score 11):

Things that can help in general :

- Headers should be similar to common browsers, including :

  - **User-Agent** : use a recent one (see https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/), or better, use a random recent one if you make multiple requests (see https://github.com/skratchdot/random-useragent)
  - **Accept-Language** : something like "*en,en-US;q=0,5*" (adapt for your language)
  - **Accept**: a standard one would be like "*text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8*"
- Navigation :

  - If you make multiple request, put a **random timeout** between them
  - If you open links found in a page, set the **Referer** header accordingly
  - Or better, simulate mouse activity to move, click and follow link
- **Images** should be enabled
- **Javascript** should be enabled

  - Check that "**navigator.plugins**" and "**navigator.language**" are set in the client javascript page context
- Use proxies

Answer (score 3):

The first answer is a bit off selenium is still detectable as its a webdriver and not a normal browser it has hardcoded values that can be detected using javascript most websites use fingerprinting libraries that can find these values luckily there is a patched chromedriver called [undetecatble_chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) that bypasses such checks