# how can i get website html code using requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing

I repeated all the steps as in the tutorial but I don’t get the code. Although a couple of days ago everything worked

I write a simple code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://i-teka.kz/almaty/spisokaptek'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.text)
```

and after running i get:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

but should get the full html code
I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python requests bot detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966787/python-requests-bot-detection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The may be checking for various headers. You can try various headers and find the required headers.

or

There is a library called requestez which simplifies all this and does it automatically.
you can do

`pip install requestez`

and then

```py
import requestez
url = 'https://i-teka.kz/almaty/spisokaptek'
page = requestez.Session().get(url)
print(page)
```

[image: image of output]

[image: part of the html of the page]