# Error in Scraping a Webpage in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape this page:
http://photo.net/nikon-camera-forum/00aoms
I'm using the Requests Package in Python however although the page is fine and it loads when I enter the url in a browser I get this error as the output of requests.get.text and I don't know what's the problem:

```
"photo.net Temporarily Unavailable 
photo.net 
Sun Jul 13 19:26:33 EDT 2014 &mdash; photo.net is down temporarily for 
system maintenance. Please visit us again later."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site has a simple `User-Agent` header check, [provide it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/how-to-send-user-agent-in-requests-library-in-python):

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://photo.net/nikon-camera-forum/00aoms', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4)'})
>>> print response.text
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">var _sf_startpt=(new Date()).getTime()</script>

<title>D800 wifi options? - Photo.net Nikon Forum</title>
...
```

FYI, what was without passing the header:

```
>>> response = requests.get('http://photo.net/nikon-camera-forum/00aoms')
>>> print response.text
<html><head><title>photo.net Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<center><h2>photo.net </h2>
<p><i>Sun Jul 13 19:46:33 EDT 2014</i>&nbsp;&mdash; photo.net is down temporarily for 
system maintenance.  Please visit us again later.
</center>
</body>
</html>
```