# Scraping web content using xpath won't work

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, lxml

I'm using xpath to scrape a amazon webpage particular, but it doesn't work. Can any one give me some advice? Here's the link to that page: 
[a link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B009CX5VN2)

I want to scrape these: "Fun, credit card-sized prints"
The code i'm using is here:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B009CX5VN2'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
feature_bullets = tree.xpath('//*[@id="feature-bullets"]/ul/li[1]/span/text()')
```

But the feature_bullets is always empty. Really need some help.

Comment: I draw your attention to the second paragraph of section 3 of [Amazon UK's Conditions of Use & Sale](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_cou/279-7931089-4191464?ie=UTF8&nodeId=1040616).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML that I download doesn't match your expectations. Here is the expression that works for me:

```
tree.xpath('//div[@id="technicalProductFeaturesATF"]/ul/li[1]/text()')
```

Complete program:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B009CX5VN2'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
feature_bullets = tree.xpath('//div[@id="technicalProductFeaturesATF"]/ul/li/text()')

pprint(feature_bullets)
```

Result:

```
$ python foo.py 
['Fun, credit card-sized prints',
 'LCD film counter and shooting mode display',
 'Camera mounted mirror for self portraits',
 'Powered by CR2 Batteries, Built-in, Automatic electronic flash',
 'Fujifilm Instax Mini 25 + 30 Instax Mini Film']
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I noticed the html the program was reading is slightly different from the html in chrome or any other browser, although I don't why that's the case. Maybe each browser has its own standard format.

Comment: You might consider [sending a user-agent string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/how-to-send-user-agent-in-requests-library-in-python) along with your request. If you use the [user-agent from your browser](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/), you'll probably get the same page.