# Having issues with Python xpath scraping

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

I'm back again with a question for the wonderful people here :)

Ive recently begun getting back into python (50% done at codcademy lol) and decided to make a quick script for web-scraping the spot price of gold in CAD. This will eventually be a part of a much bigger script... but Im VERY rusty and thought it would be a good project.

My issue:
I have been following the guide over at http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/ to accomplish my goal, however my script always returns/prints

```
<Element html at 0xRANDOM>
```

with RANDOM being a (i assume) random hex number. This happens no matter what website I seem to use.

My Code:

```
#!/bin/python
#Scrape current gold spot price in CAD

from lxml import html
import requests

def scraped_price():
    page = requests.get('http://goldprice.org/gold-price-canada.html')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    print "The full page is: ", tree #added for debug WHERE ERROR OCCURS
    bid = tree.xpath("//span[@id='gpotickerLeftCAD_price']/text()")
    print "Scraped content: ", bid
    return bid
gold_scraper = scraped_price()
```

My research:

1) www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

This is where I figured out to use '//span' to find all 'span' objects and then used the @id to narrow it down to the one I need.

2)[Scraping web content using xpath won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063774/scraping-web-content-using-xpath-wont-work)

This makes me think I simply have a bad tree.xpath setup. However I cannot seem to figure out where or why.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<Element html at 0xRANDOM>`

What you see printed is the `lxml.html`'s `Element` class *string representation*. If you want to see the actual HTML content, use `tostring()`:

```
print(html.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

You are also getting `Scraped content:  []` printed which really means that there were no elements matching the locator. And, if you would see the previously printed out HTML, there is actually no element with `id="gpotickerLeftCAD_price"` in the downloaded source.

The prices on this particular site are retrieved dynamically with continuous JSONP GET requests issued periodically. You can either look into simulating these requests, or stay on a higher level automating a browser via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). Demo (using [`PhantomJS` headless browser](http://phantomjs.org/)):

```
>>> import time
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> 
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.get("http://goldprice.org/gold-price-canada.html")
>>> while True:
...     print(driver.find_element_by_id("gpotickerLeftCAD_price").text)
...     time.sleep(1)
... 
1,595.28
1,595.28
1,595.28
1,595.28
1,595.28
1,595.19
...
```

Comment: switching to html.tostring gives me an error:  Type 'str' cannot be serialized

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand, My code has the html.fromstring section within the variable 'tree' which when changed to 'tostring' gives a serialize error.  Im not sure how to implement your fix into my code. I apologize, its been a long day and Im not working at full capacity lol  -   maybe selenium would be a better idea for me lol

Comment: @L8NIT3TR0UBL3 it's okay, here is what I'm executing: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/353738460807a04faa2a. Also, updated the answer with a full story.

Comment: absolutely perfect! I apologize for being so dense lol I may try both ways and see which i like best :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just a quick addon, if PhantomJS needs to be downloaded for this to work, how could I bundle the binary or at least libraries so I can make an executable from the eventual bigger program?

Comment: @L8NIT3TR0UBL3 sorry, this is not something I can help you with. Happy scraping!