# Authenticate to Google Drive and download spreadsheet with Python urllib2/requests

Tags: python, excel, http, download, python-requests

I would like to download a document I have in my Google Drive authenticating to Google (I only want certain users to be able to access it and do not want to publish it on the web).

I have tried using `requests` but apparently I am doing something wrong.
From a browser I can download my document going to the address
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<document key>/export?format=xls`.

So in my python script I do the following:

```
import os
import requests
import shutil
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

remote = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<document key>/export?format=xls"
username = os.environ['GOOGLEUSERNAME']
password = os.environ['GOOGLEPASSWORD']
r = requests.get(remote, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password))
if r.status_code == 200:
  with open("document.xls","wb") as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

however the resulting `document.xls` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might actually be possible what you are trying to do, but here are *some* reasons why it will be non-trivial(by no means a complete list):

1. Google is usually blocking `user-agents` that are non-browsers(like your Python script) for browser intended content (for security reasons); you would have to [spoof it, which is actually easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/how-to-send-user-agent-in-requests-library-in-python)
2. Multi-factor authentication - you would have to turn that off (easy, but you open yourself up for being hacked...)
3. [Session-cookie - aka `security cookie`](http://www.google.com/policies/technologies/types/); (not so easy to get ahold of)

## What you should do instead

Use the [official google-drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/). Also, the [Python client library](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python) has a nice tutorial and [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads) describes how to download files from google-drive.

If you want to write even less code, then libraries like [PyDrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive) will make your live even easier.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have a reference for point (1)? I never observed this.

Comment: Thats my own experience when I tried to parse google websites years ago.

Comment: I have not had issues in this regard, using wget and Python without attempting to fake the user agent (see below).

Answer (score 2):

I might have a simple solution for you, depending on what exactly the auth requirements are. You are saying

> I only want certain users to be able to access it and do not want to
>   publish it on the web

From this statement alone, it may be sufficient for you to create a "secret" link for your document, and share this among your users. You can then *easily* retrieve this document automatically, for instance with *wget*, and specify the format, e.g. `csv`:

```
wget -O data.csv "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/***SHARED-SECRET***/export?format=csv"
```

Or, in Python (2):

```
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar

spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/***SHARED-SECRET***/export?format=csv"
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(CookieJar()))
response = opener.open(spreadsheet_url) 
with open("data.csv", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```

I am actually using that in production, it works reliably, without faking the user agent.

Comment: In regards to the user-agent blocking this will work - as those links are created to be downloaded by anything. But try scraping google.com or in this case a random google-doc document without creating links and your script gets blocked because of your user-agent. Its web-security 101

Comment: Of course you have a point in general. The whole point of my answer is that *if he can* slightly change his approach about authentication, then there is very simple way that works reliably, for the reason you pointed out again: it's a document protected by a shared secret only.