# Text not visible Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Why am I not getting the text? I've used this script on many websites and never came across this issue.

```
import scrapy.selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Prijsvergelijking_Final.items import PrijsvergelijkingFinalItem

vendors = []
for line in open("vendors.txt", "r"):
    vendors.append(line.strip("\n\-"))
e = {}
for vendor in vendors:
    e[vendor] = True

class ArtcrafttvSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ARTCRAFTTV"
    allowed_domains = ["artencraft.be"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.artencraft.be/nl/beeld-en-geluid/televisie"]
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="next"]',)), callback = "parse_start_url",follow = True),)    
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//ul[@class='product-overview list']/li")
        for product in products:
            item = PrijsvergelijkingFinalItem()
            item["Product_a"] = product.xpath(".//a/span/h3/text()").extract_first().strip().replace("-","")
            item["Product_price"] = product.xpath(".//a/h4/text()").extract_first()
            for word in item['Product_a'].split(" "):
                if word in e:
                    item['item_vendor'] = word              
            yield item
```

Website code:

[image: HTML]

Results after script is run:

[image: Results]

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Comment: You talking about the price?

Comment: Yes i do talk about the prices

Comment: @Wouter: Try a different XPath for the price, like `.//a/h4/(/text())[last()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer would be:

**You have a wrong xpath for price field value**

Detailed:

do not always assume that page structure will be same as what is displayed on your screen. it is **NOT always WYSIWYG**

for some reason i see that `inspect element`(firefox) shows a price value as child of **`//a/h4`** tag but if you will analyze the page source that is downloaded, you will see that price value is present on page but is it no child of **`//a/h4`** tag but it is a child of **`//a`** tag so **`//a/text()`** would give you the desired value

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the prices are loaded in from Javascript or something- when I pull down the page from Python I get no prices anywhere.

There's two possible things going on here: First, the prices might be loading in with Javascript. If that's the case, I recommend looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440563/629110 and the library [dryscape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape).

If the prices are being blocked because of your user agent, you can try to change your user agent to a real browser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606260/629110 .

Try the user agent first (since it is easier).