# Extracting specific line using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I was wondering how to pull an exact line from a website or simply make it print everything where a certain word is. Example "my dog is a beautiful dog" if I use the word beautiful I want Python to locate the whole sentence and return it.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://prisleje.dk/?page_id=2').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

print(soup.find("eksempler"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://prisleje.dk/?page_id=2', headers={'User-Agent': 'My Agent'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(text=re.compile('eksempler')))
```

Output:

```
eksempler på sager vi kan hjælpe med
```

**Note:**

You need to pass some [headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python) as the site is blocking the default `User-Agent`.

If you're not familiar with `regex` you can read this- [Python Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).