# Can't receive data from particular website via python, SSL error

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I try to make response using a particular link. `https://www.fastwin.io:9873/getEnvelopeRank`
But got bogged down with problem.

When I try to make request through the browser I get normal response. But if I try to make request through `requests` lib I will get

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

requests to other sites work fine.

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.fastwin.io:9873/getEnvelopeRank")

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a self signed certificate? Either get a proper one or accept self signed certificates in your request. Strangely enough tho, I don't get any certificate errors going towards that site o0

Comment: I had this same issue pop up some time ago regarding get requests to library repos using conda.  The problem turned out to be a corrupted install.  I had moved a file into another folder that I shouldn't have moved.  I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda and my get requests went off without a hitch afterward.  Not saying it will work for sure but you might just try reinstalling your python distro.  It worked for me.

Comment: I've just completely reinstalled python3.7.2 and I had same issue. I've already had installation of last version of certifi. in venv folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to a website which uses SSL. You can recognize this from the url.
"https", Note the s at the end. This is a indication the website uses a certificate.

Most likely when you send a `user agent` with your request you are good to go.
More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python). This could fix your problem.