# Does requests rely on selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I am running some crawls in order to test if the results I get deviate. For this effort I created two test suites, the first one I created with the requests and BeautifulSoup library, the other one is based on selenium. I would like to find out, if pages detect both bots in the same way.

But I am still unsure if I am right, by assuming that requests and BeautifulSoup are independent from Selenium.

I hope its not a dump question, but I haven't find any proper answer yet (maybe because of the wrong keywords). However, any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

I checked the requests documentation. I wrote a mail to the developer, without any answer. And of course I checked on google. I found something about scrapy vs selenium but well... are requests and BeautyfulSoup related to scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python requests module does not use Selenium, neither does BeautifulSoup. Both will run independent of a web browser. Both are pure python implementations.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium automates browsers](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), so you'll present to a web service with the user-agent string and other variables that the browser you choose to drive with Selenium would present.

[You can specify user-agent string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python) when you use requests, or not, but requests doesn't drive a browser inherently, so you'll be presenting as a different entity from the user-agent perspective, like python-requests/2.18.4.

[BeautifulSoup is a parser](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8v3owv/what_is_the_default_user_agent_when_scraping_the/), and so it presents to a web service through another library (like requests); it doesn't have its own native presentation.