# No response from `request.get()` for NASDAQ webpage

Tags: python, python-requests, finance

I am able to open this [url](https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/earnings?date=2021-02-23) via a browser and see the response in `json` format. However, when I use the `requests` module, there is no response from the method.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/earnings?date=2021-02-23')
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Well, what do you get? What is in response?

Comment: Nothing, it gets stuck...that is the problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
url = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/earnings?date=2021-02-23'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

**Explanation**

The site is blocking requests from python. Refer to explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57155793/8350440)

Answer (score 0):

When adding the headers of the query that appear when inspecting the element in chrome, the request works well in python:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/earnings?date=2021-02-23',headers={"authority":"api.nasdaq.com","scheme":"https","path":"/api/calendar/earnings?date=2021-02-23","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache","accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36","origin":"https://www.nasdaq.com","sec-fetch-site":"same-site","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","sec-fetch-dest":"empty","referer":"https://www.nasdaq.com/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7"})
```