# why beautiful soup select method returns None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I needed to **extract youtube links** with their **names**, from **youtube playlists**.
So I just tried to use `SelectorGadget`(Chrome Extension) for extracting CSS tag, but when I'm trying to get anything about the like BeautifulSoup returns `none`, I don't where am I going wrong.

below is the code I wrote:

```py
from os import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

try:
    # checking url format
    url_pattern = re.compile("^(?:http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_~:\-\/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=`^.%]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_~:\-\/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=`^.%]+$") 

    # playlist_url = input("Enter your youtbe playlist url: ")
    # getting input directly from user commandline
    playlist_url = sys.argv[1]

    if not bool(url_pattern.match(playlist_url)) :
        raise ValueError("Enter valid link")

    get_links_from_youtube_playlist(playlist_url)

except ValueError as value_error:
    print(value_error)
```

then I will pass the URL to another function:

```py
def get_links_from_youtube_playlist(youtube_playlist_url):

    request_response = requests.get(youtube_playlist_url)

    # using "html.parser" lib
    # soup_object = BeautifulSoup(request_response.text, 'html.parser')
    # using "lxml" - Processing XML and HTML with Python
    soup_object = BeautifulSoup(request_response.text, 'lxml')

    # not working?!
    url_list = soup_object.select("#video-title")
    print(url_list)
    # this is not working too?!
    div_content = soup_object.find("div", attrs={"class" : "content"})
    print(div_content)
```

Also, I run it via below command:

```sh
python3 test.py https://www.youtube.com/playlist\?list\=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab
```

My output is None when printing the BeautifulSoup object after either `select` or f`enter code here`ind methods. Shouldn't it find anything meaningful because the id is present in the page?

**selector gadget** shows me `#video-title` only when clicking on that section, even I could not access the `div` how should I extract link and link's name?

Comment: There's no `id="video-title"` anywhere in that page. There are lots of `class="video-title"`. It sounds like this ID is something being added by the extension when you click on it, but how can BS know which item you want?

Comment: Use `.video-title` to select by class.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, for hellping, but I've tried `url_list = soup_object.select(".video-title")` it agian return nothing ([ ]) `

Comment: The page returned by `requests.get()` is different from what the browser gets. YouTube is apparently checking the user agent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python for how to customize the user agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube checks the user agent to determine what kind of page to return. If you send the user agent corresponding to a real browser, you'll get the response you expect. `video-title` is a class, not an ID, so change the selector to `.video-title`.

```
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

def get_links_from_youtube_playlist(youtube_playlist_url):

    request_response = requests.get(youtube_playlist_url, headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"})

    soup_object = BeautifulSoup(request_response.text, 'lxml')
    url_list = soup_object.select(".video-title")
    pp.pprint(url_list)

get_links_from_youtube_playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab')
```

Output:

```
[<div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>,
 <div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>]
```