# Issue about Requests a url response 404, but success in browser AND scrape tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** the tags on the website. I could open the url successfully on Chrome, however, when using `requests` in `Python3`, it shows `404 error`. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://vote4.hk/zh/district/2019/A04"

r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

tags = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "MuiChip-label MuiChip-labelSmall"})
tags_list = []
for tag in tags:
    tags_list.append(tag.text)
    print(tag.text)
```

I also tried with `Selenium`, but when it automatically open the url, it shows a pop-up window and it cannot get the `pagesource`.

I want to **scrape** the tags. Could somebody help me fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It could be that you need to set a User-Agent string in the header.  Some sites out there that deny anything that looks like a scraper.  This should be a word of caution as the site may forbid scraping and ban your IP if you attempt to do so.  There is a good answer on SO on how to set the User-Agent string, if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python  Also, if the content is dynamically loaded, then simple static scraping isn't going to work--you'll need to use a tool that can actually render the page.

Comment: have you tried loading the page in your browser with javascript disabled? you will see th page has no content as its all loaded via javascript. requests only gets the source it wont get any content thats added in later y javascript

Comment: Could you please provide some code on how to scrape the page loading with JavaScript?

Comment: One method to scrape page with JavaScript is using `Selenium`. However, when using Selenium to open the page, it pops up a window and cannot get the data. Could somebody help me how to deal with that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is that this site loads all its content through javascript changing the dom elelemnt. the `requests` library will only fetch the page source it wont see any java script updates to the content. If you try loading this in a browser with java script disabled you will see the same result as you do from pythons `requests` library.

[image]

Infact if you view the page source in your browser or you look in the text that requests get it actually tells you that it will give a 404 error then javascript will reformat the url and call again in the right format.

**html from the page source**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages</title>
<script type="5d373f9ebf22760453cbae19-text/javascript">
      // Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages
      // https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages
      // Copyright (c) 2016 Rafael Pedicini, licensed under the MIT License
      // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      // This script takes the current url and converts the path and query
      // string into just a query string, and then redirects the browser
      // to the new url with only a query string and hash fragment,
      // e.g. http://www.foo.tld/one/two?a=b&c=d#qwe, becomes
      // http://www.foo.tld/?p=/one/two&q=a=b~and~c=d#qwe
      // Note: this 404.html file must be at least 512 bytes for it to work
      // with Internet Explorer (it is currently > 512 bytes)
      // If you're creating a Project Pages site and NOT using a custom domain,
      // then set segmentCount to 1 (enterprise users may need to set it to > 1).
      // This way the code will only replace the route part of the path, and not
      // the real directory in which the app resides, for example:
      // https://username.github.io/repo-name/one/two?a=b&c=d#qwe becomes
      // https://username.github.io/repo-name/?p=/one/two&q=a=b~and~c=d#qwe
      // Otherwise, leave segmentCount as 0.
      var segmentCount = 0;
      var l = window.location;
      l.replace(
        l.protocol + '//' + l.hostname + (l.port ? ':' + l.port : '') +
        l.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 1 + segmentCount).join('/') + '/?p=/' +
        l.pathname.slice(1).split('/').slice(segmentCount).join('/').replace(/&/g, '~and~') +
        (l.search ? '&q=' + l.search.slice(1).replace(/&/g, '~and~') : '') +
        l.hash
      );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/95c75768/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-settings="5d373f9ebf22760453cbae19-|49" defer=""></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show how to scrap the data with code?

Comment: Thats a totally different question and i suggest you ask a new question or do some reseach or more testing with something like selenium. if after that its still not working then open a new question with your specific selenium problem