# python requests problem: cloudflare error message "enable cookies"

Tags: python, web, request, python-requests, cloudflare

I was planning on creating a basic web scraper for the site Sneakersnstuff.com however my efforts were stopped early due to an error. When requesting to the url https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/, rather than displaying the html of the website, or even the entrance captcha, I am redirected to a cloudflare page with the error message "enable cookies". Both my code and the response are shown below

```
import requests
import cfscrape


session = requests.session()

response = session.get('https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/')

print(response.headers)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <title>Access denied | www.sneakersnstuff.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css"
        media="screen,projection" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
    </style>


    <!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->



</head>

<body>
    <div id="cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please
            enable cookies.</div>
        <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
            <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
                <h1>
                    <span class="cf-error-type" data-translate="error">Error</span>
                    <span class="cf-error-code">1020</span>
                    <small class="heading-ray-id">Ray ID: 578133293d83e0d6 &bull; 2020-03-22 16:13:25 UTC</small>
                </h1>
                <h2 class="cf-subheadline">Access denied</h2>
            </div><!-- /.header -->

            <section></section><!-- spacer -->

            <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
                <div class="cf-columns two">
                    <div class="cf-column">
                        <h2 data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
                        <p>This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.</p>

                    </div>



                </div>
            </div><!-- /.section -->

            <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
                <p>
                    <span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong>578133293d83e0d6</strong></span>
                    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
                    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Your IP</span>: 96.241.108.243</span>
                    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
                    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a
                        href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link"
                        target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

                </p>
            </div><!-- /.error-footer -->


        </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
    </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window._cf_translation = {};


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have attempted using a library reccomend by many called cfscrape to no avail.

Comment: When using requests, I solved the issue for me by providing a user agent in the headers that is supported. Before I used a user agent that caused problem. Now I changed it to Mozilla (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python) which works. Unfortunately, the response messages were not really helpful to find out what the issue was.

Answer (score 8):

Adding `Browser/User-Agent Filtering` to cloudscraper did the trick for me.

```
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Adding Browser / User-Agent Filtering should help ie. 

# will give you only desktop firefox User-Agents on Windows
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(browser={'browser': 'firefox','platform': 'windows','mobile': False})

html = scraper.get("https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Comment: suggest you get the response object as `r` and then you can get `r.content` separately but also check `r.status_code` etc

Answer (score 0):

```py
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

html = scraper.get("https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Output:

```
cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareReCaptchaProvider: Cloudflare reCaptcha detected, unfortunately you haven't loaded an anti reCaptcha provider correctly via the 'recaptcha' parameter.
```

Next Step ?

3rd Party reCaptcha Solvers
Description

cloudscraper currently supports the following 3rd party reCaptcha solvers, should you require them.

```
anticaptcha
deathbycaptcha
2captcha
9kw
return_response
```

Comment: When trying this i consistently receive the error, cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareCode1020: Cloudflare has blocked this request (Code 1020 Detected).

Comment: @ChrisYun indeed your device got blocked due to multiple request.

Comment: How can this be fixed?

Comment: @ChrisYun you can use `requests` library with `proxies` or `socks`

Comment: is there any way to do this locally without the use of proxies?