# Using locust to simulate load test from android or iOS phones

Tags: user-agent, locust

Is there a way to simulate an android user agent in locust.io load testing? I have a server I need to load test and they check if the call is from an android or iOS phone

Answer (score 1):

Locust's http client for HttpUser is based on the requests module. This should work for you.

[Sending "User-agent" using Requests library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python)