# python finding embedded mp4 file with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to bs4!

I have looked up many tutorials but nothing will work...
I want to scrape the mp4 file from a site but the embedded stuff looks different than on the tutorials...
I have tried the find and find_all function but cant get it to work.
Can anyone help?

```
<div class="rmp-playlist-container">
<div class="rmp-playlist-player-wrapper">
<div id="rmpPlayer"></div>
</div>
</div>
<p><script>var playlistData = [{src: {mp4:["https://wantedurl.mp4"]},"contentMetadata": {"title": "video1",   "thumbnail":"https://somethumbnail.jpg","poster": [   "https://someposter.jpg"]}
```

current code:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'From': 'tikkanenfelix@gmail.com'  # This is another valid field
}

base_url = "url"

r = requests.get(base_url,headers=headers)

patt = re.compile(r'mp4:\s*\["(.+?)"\]')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
print(soup)

for e in soup.find_all('script'):
    m = patt.search(e.string)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: Please include your code attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regular expression` to find all the links

```py
import re
text = """
<div class="rmp-playlist-container">
<div class="rmp-playlist-player-wrapper">
<div id="rmpPlayer"></div>
</div>
</div>
<p><script>var playlistData = [{src: {mp4:["https://wantedurl.mp4"]},"contentMetadata": {"title": "video1",   "thumbnail":"https://somethumbnail.jpg","poster": [   "https://someposter.jpg"]}
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
re.findall("https.*.mp4", soup.script.string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try regular expressions to parse the javascript text.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

patt = re.compile(r'mp4:\s*\["(.+?)"\]')

data = '''\
<div class="rmp-playlist-container">
<div class="rmp-playlist-player-wrapper">
<div id="rmpPlayer"></div>
</div>
</div>
<p><script>var playlistData = [{src: {mp4:["https://wantedurl.mp4"]},"contentMetadata": {"title": "video1",   "thumbnail":"https://somethumbnail.jpg","poster": [   "https://someposter.jpg"]}}];
</script>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.find_all('script'):
    m = patt.search(e.string)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: i get an error message that looks like this: m = patt.search(e.string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: What can I say without seeing your code? The above answer works on my machine. You must be doing something else.

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://repl.it/@JustinEzequiel/bs4ViciousSystemsoftware).

Comment: Do I have to output the source code of the site into a string for it to be able to work?

Comment: No, you do not. So long as you load it into BeautifulSoup. Post your code, why don't you?

Comment: Refusing to post any code makes it much more difficult to help you.

Comment: Print out `r.content`. You may be getting different content than what your browser gets. Try adding a User-Agent header to your request.

Comment: And if you are getting errors, do not paraphrase but paste the full traceback as part of your question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python

Comment: still getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python/venv/videodownloader.py", line 15, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
  File "C:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 307, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: tried with r.text aswell and got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python/venv/videodownloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    m = patt.search(e.string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Easier if you can share the URL instead of hiding that information from us. Print out `r.status_code` and `r.reason`. Did I not ask you to print out `r.content` and check if you are getting the HTML you expect?

Comment: r.reason says OK and r.status_code says 200.  thanks for your help :) ill try and figure it out