# Page 404 through Python Requests but loads fine through browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, browser, python-requests, bscscan

Getting page 404 with Python Requests but I can access the page no problem through my browser. I can access other pages that are formatted exactly the same as this page and they load no problem.

Have already tried changing headers with no luck.

My Code:

```
string_page = str(page)
with requests.Session() as s:

    resp = s.get('https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress=0x470862af0cf8d27ebfe0ff77b0649779c29186db&a=&sid=f58c1cdefacc680b799412c7645ed7f7&p='+string_page)

    page_info = str(resp.text)

print(page_info)
```

I have also tried with urllib and the same thing happens

Comment: Have you tried [sending an “user-agent” using Requests library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python)? Maybe "the user-agent should be specified as a field in the header."

Comment: You probably need to be signed in to get to the page in the URL. When you use Python, it's accessing the page as a "guest".

Comment: tried the header solutions. no luck.

Comment: im not logged in on my browser and it still works

Comment: You perhaps logged in earlier and the browser remembered cookies and which is why it works for you. However, you should share the url to get more accurate suggestion, not like the broken one in your post.

Comment: i dont have an account on the website, so have never logged in.

This is the direct link to the page:
https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress=0x470862af0cf8d27ebfe0ff77b0649779c29186db&a=&sid=f58c1cdefacc680b799412c7645ed7f7&p=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix it, but try adding this in the header maybe it might work

```
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
```

Comment: yeah tried that already. no luck unfortunately