# Python requests failed with authorization

Tags: python, python-requests, download

I am trying to get some videos downloaded from the website. So when I enter the url in the browser, the webpage will ask me for a username and password with a little window popped out. After I enter them there, the file automatically starts to download. But I got 404 when I tried to use requests.get with an auth parameter to do the same thing.

Code:

```
url = video_links[0]
print("url: ", url)

filename = os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)
print('filename: ', filename)

r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
print(r.status_code)
```

Output:

```
url:  http://datasets.d2.mpi-inf.mpg.de/movieDescription/protected/avi/0001_American_Beauty/0001_American_Beauty_00.00.51.926-00.00.54.129.avi

filename:  0001_American_Beauty_00.00.51.926-00.00.54.129.avi

404
```

[popped window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BID8D.png)

I have tried to pass a user-agent in. Still not working.

Code ver2:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/something more',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

output:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>401 Unauthorized</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Unauthorized</h1>\n<p>This server could not verify that you\nare authorized to access the document\nrequested.  Either you supplied the wrong\ncredentials (e.g., bad password), or your\nbrowser doesn\'t understand how to supply\nthe credentials required.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at datasets.d2.mpi-inf.mpg.de Port 443</address>\n</body></html>\n'
```

Comment: hi, is [`HTTPBasicAuth`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) failing? Perhaps set your [user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python) to a known browser as well

Comment: Please post your code and out as text. Screenshots of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: show real URL for this page. How do you send login and password? Maybe browser sends it in different way. OR maybe browser uses some JavaScript for redirect - but  `requests` can't run JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just like jspcal said, everything is working now. Thanks

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
```