# Changing login devices

Tags: python, web

im trying to change the login devices into a website. For example, when i login to instagram i receive this email from them. I want to be able to change "Samsung SHV-E275K" and then count the number of devices from a user. How would i make changes to the device without actually changing teh device? Has anyone had experience of this before? I have tried using a virtual machine but i would like to be able to perform this from a python program.

```
Samsung SHV-E275K · Instagram · Cluj-Napoca, Romania
 
September 1 at 7:04 PM (PDT)
```

Comment: Do you mean [you want to change the User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests library in python.
If you don't have it installed just do `pip install requests` from your terminal. Use this code

```
import requests

headers = {
'User-Agent': <samsung-user-agent>
}
req = request.get('https:www.instagram.com', headers=headers)
```

Comment: perfect, thank you