# request.get to seemingly valid URL returns 404 status code / fails

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Valid URL fails requests.get

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL is a valid URL as is not redirects

DOES NOT WORK

```
import requests

url6 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL'
r = requests.get(url6)
```

returns

False

404

[]

or more simply

```
requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL')
```

<Response [404]>

WORKS
this for example (different page on same source)

```
requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMG?p=AMG')
```

returns
True
200

Comment: You have to add headers to your request. Does this answer your question? [Sending "User-agent" using Requests library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python).

Comment: They probably have something in place to stop webscraping, try setting a user-agent header

Answer (score 0):

I added headers to your request. More specifically, I added the user agent.

```
import requests

url6 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL'
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url6, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that adding user-agent helps

```
r = requests.get(url8, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom'})
```

Comment: I usually use a well-known user agent string. A server may return different things based on the user agent.