# Troubleshooting (Fear and Greed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to access a web page using the requests library in Python. My code looks like this:

```
import requests
link = requests.get("www.example.com")
print(link.text)
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
"I'm a teapot. You're a bot." Meaning <Response [418]>
```

It looks like I'm trying to access the CNN DataViz API and I'm getting a response status code of 418 indicating that the server is rejecting it and I'm a bot.

Could someone help me understand what's going on and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Contact the server admin to clarify under what circumstances the server may return this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason might be your user agent not being detected.

Consider setting it up for your request.

Instructions: [Sending "User-agent" using Requests library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python)

Comment: headers = {'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0','From': 'mymailaddress@hotmail.com'}
link=requests.get("https:....",headers=headers) -Still same 418 :/

Comment: Thank you gave me hint However, I am unable to post the solution they close this question. Link here. https://medium.com/@8birkan/im-a-teapot-you-re-a-bot-57fbdb9f6096