# Website table scraping with python and beautifulsoup returns "none" or empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this table with a simple request, but after trying using the table class, it returns 'none':

```
table = soup.find("table", class_ = "hp")
```

and trying any table returns empty:

```
table = soup.find_all("table")
```

How can I fix this?

Here's the complete code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/year/2024/1"
response = requests.get(url)
#print(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table", class_ = "hp")
print(table)
```

i'm using pandas with the goal of filing an .csv later.

Comment: Did you check what `response.text` holds before passing to `BeautifulSoup`?

Answer (score 0):

You're being blocked by the website, most likely because of the default Requests User-Agent header ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)), `python-requests/<version>`.

If you check the value of `response.text`, it reads something like

```
Sorry, something went wrong. You can contact us via <email>, should the problem persist.
```

You should [set the User-Agent header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python) to something different. For example,

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/year/2024/1"
response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "your-user-agent-string")
#print(response.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table", class_ = "hp")
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by utilising pandas `read_html` the example below yields the full table from the url provided.
From there you can cleanse and export as csv `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/year/2024/1"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.read_html(r.content)[0]
```

*Note: you will also have to pip install lxml & html5lib